# How to find the employee with most customers

Tags: mysql

I have en employee table that looks like this

```
employeenumber int(11) PK 
lastname varchar(50) 
firstname varchar(50)
```

And a customer table that look like this

```
customernumber int(11) PK 
salesrepemployeenumber int(11) 
creditlimit double
```

How do I find the employee with most customers?
I know I have to make a query of the salesrepemployeenumber column in the customer table to find out which employee has the most customer with a count, max??? And then i need to return the employee number and the full name.

What is the solution???

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the queries you have tried but don't return the desired result (and what they returned instead).

Answer (score 1):

Use a join/count/group by:

```
SELECT 
    employees.employeenumber, -- employee id
    employees.lastname, -- sample employee name
    COUNT(customers.customernumber) AS customer_count -- the number of customers
FROM employees
LEFT OUTER JOIN customers -- I'm using a left join so we can see people with 0 as well
    -- get some shorter column names man
    ON customers.salesrepemployeenumber = employees.employeenumber
GROUP BY employees.employeenumber
```

In short, you select all of the employees, then merge them with the results of the customers tables, then group them by the employee's id. By using `COUNT` during a `GROUP BY` operation, we can count the number of distinct entries to a specific group.

From there it's a matter of selecting the largest value out of the results, which is as simple as using `LIMIT`/`ORDER BY`

```
SELECT ...
ORDER BY customer_count DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: ...assuming there's no tie for first place

Comment: Absolutely, though op suggested a single result you can probably get away with a MAX + HAVING, or a subquery to get all top performers

Answer (score 1):

Join the two tables, group them by the primary key of the employee table and order the results by count descendingly, getting the first result (having the most results)

```
select employee.salesrepemployeenumber, employee.lastname, employee.firstname, count(*) as result
from employee
join customer
on employee.employeenumber = customer.salesrepemployeenumber
group by employeenumber
order by count(*) desc limit 0, 1;
```

Comment: The only case I don't see this covering is a case where there hasn't been a customer yet but there are employees.

Comment: @Rogue in that case any employee has exactly 0 customers, which do not mee the criteria of "has the most customer". If that case should yield an employee, then we can solve that as well, naturally, with a left join.